# Self-define BroadcastReceiver constructor don't work

Tags: java, android

I define a BroadcastReceiver in Android.The code like this.

```
public static class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private Handler handler;

    public DataReceiver(){

    }

    public DataReceiver(Handler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        OutputData outputData = (OutputData) intent.getSerializableExtra("OutputData");
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = outputData;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Then I initial BroadCastReceiver in Activity and register it like this

```
DataReceiver mReceiver = new DataReceiver(new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        OutputData outputData = (OutputData) msg.obj;
        updateUI(outputData);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);
}
```

when I send a broadcast in Service ,it raise NullPointException like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.sendMessage(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference
```

It says the handler in onReceive method is null.But I have already initial handler in constructor. Why that happend.

Comment: It isn't crashing for me. Are your sure `mReceiver` is being initialized before `onResume()`?